# Where is the setting setVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_NOTIFICATION, false) in the phone?

Tags: android, setting, vibration

i made an app that messes with the system vibrate settings. namely, it turns them off.

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_RINGER, AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_OFF);
audioManager.setVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_NOTIFICATION, AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_OFF);
System.putInt(ctx.getContentResolver(), VIBRATE_IN_SILENT, 0);
```

i wonder now, where i can turn the vibration manually back on. the ringer vibrate setting can be found in the Sound settings, but where is the notification setting? the setting in the SMS app is still on "vibrate always", but the phone does not vibrate anymore when receiving a text. can this setting just be turned on/off programmatically?

btw: i am using a Nexus One with Android 2.3.3

Thx
Simon

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is the exact same thing you did above except set `AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_OFF` to `AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_ON`

Comment: yeah, sure i get that. the question is how can i set that manually? i can not find an option for that in the android settings (like the ringer vibrate setting in Settings - Sound - Vibrate).