# How to turn off vibrator systemwide in Android?

Tags: android

How to turn off the vibrator systemwide in Android? Vibrator is boring.

Answer (score 2):

A quick search on SO gave me this soution:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_RINGER, AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_OFF);
audioManager.setVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_NOTIFICATION, AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_OFF);
System.putInt(ctx.getContentResolver(), VIBRATE_IN_SILENT, 0);
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933470/where-is-the-setting-setvibratesettingaudiomanager-vibrate-type-notification-f)